# How to use variables from different class in NLog.Config?

Tags: c#, path, config, nlog

I have a Class with a `static` field which holds a path.

```
public static class PfadSammlung
{
    public static string Path_Example = @"C:\temp";
}
```

How could I use this path in the `NLog.Config` file to specify the file name for the target?

```xml
<targets>
    <target xsi:type="File"
        name ="processInfo"
        fileName="C:\temp\ProcessInfoLog.log"
        layout="${longdate}  |  ProcessInfo: ${message}"
    />
</targets>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically you need to configure NLog from code. See the [offical documentation](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-API) for details and sample code.

**Update**

As Julian pointed out, you can also use variables in you config XML. Details can be found [here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Var-Layout-Renderer).

*Sample*

Config file:

```
<variable name="logDirectory" value="c:\temp" />
<targets>
    <target xsi:type="File"
        name ="processInfo"
        fileName="${var:logDirectory}"
        layout="${longdate}  |  ProcessInfo: ${message}"
    />
</targets>
```

Code:

```
LogManager.Configuration.Variables["logDirectory"] = @"c:\temp\logs";
```

Comment: thank you for the tip, but I cannot get the target to use the path. I created a Variable, set it in the code, but the target does not save the message into the file

Comment: Just to note, there is no need to move from the XML config to C# in this case.

Comment: Note that LogManager is a static class from the NLog namespace. I was trying to find it via DI which obviously won't work.